# Помогите разобраться, видимо что-то с кодировкой, Питон 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, requests, beautiful-soup

Изучаю програмирование, начал с Питона. Застрял на моменте библиотек BeautifulSoup, пологаю, что дело в кодировках. Прочитал достаточно много статей на эту тему, и не понимаю как правильно нужно сделать.
Ниже приведенный код, отлично отрабатывает когда запрашиваемый файл на латинице, но я не пойму почему на кириллице возвращаемая строка выглядит вот так:
**Р­Р» РЎСЌР№РІРіР°СЂС**

```
import bs4
exampleFile = open('D:\PythonProg\example.html')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.read())
elems = exampleSoup.select('#author')
print(elems[0].getText())
```

Код HTML запрашиваемого файла:

```
<!-- Это файл примера example.html. -->

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Заголовок веб-сайта</title>    
</head>

<body>
    <p>Загрузите мои книги по <strong>Python</strong> на моём сайте <a href="http://inventwithpython.com"></a>.</p>
    <p class="slogan">Простой подход к изучению Python!</p>
    <p>Автор<span id="author"> Эл Сэйвгарт</span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А в какой кодировке файл? Попробуйте указать эту кодировку при открытии файла, есть такой параметр `encoding=`

Comment: Благодарю Вас, всё сразу получилось. Добавил параметр при открытиии файла:
exampleFile = open('D:\PythonProg\example.html', encoding='utf-8')